# Split to get the text between separators?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a cross domain AJAX request, and because of this, I can't pass the original array from the PHP page to my HTML page. Instead, the request gets the results as a string. I have it set up so that the syntax looks like this:

```
([SCHOOL] Name [/SCHOOL][STATUS] Status [/STATUS])
([SCHOOL] Other name [/SCHOOL][STATUS] Other status [/STATUS])
```

On my HTML page, I want to be able to form an array from these different values, in the form of:

```
Array (
    [0] =>
        [0] Name
        [1] Other
    [1] =>
        [0] Name 
        [1] Other status
)
```

This way, I can use a `for` loop to get specific values.

The only problem with is that `split` only does just that, splits things. Is there a way in JS to find the text within separators, and form an array from it? In the example again, it'd find all text within the parenthesis, and form the first array, then within that array, use the text between `[SCHOOL][/SCHOOL]` for the first object, and use the text between `[STATUS][/STATUS]` for the second object.

Comment: why not send it down w/ xml or json?

Comment: Well I use `.getJSON`, but it only returns it as a string. And I'm not sure how it deals with cross domain requests.

Comment: i mean from your php. it should return a different format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would use something more suited to storing arrays on the server side. I would recommend JSON. This would be trivial to encode using php, and decode using javascript.

If you do not have that option server side, then you can use regex to parse your text. However, you must be sure that the contents does not have your delimiters within in it.

It is not clear how you get your target data structure from your source, but I would expect something like this might work for you:

```
str = "([SCHOOL] Name [/SCHOOL][STATUS] Status [/STATUS])\n\
([SCHOOL] Other name [/SCHOOL][STATUS] Other status [/STATUS])"

arr  =[]
m = str.match(/\(.+?\)/g)
for(i in m){
    matches = m[i].match(/\(\[SCHOOL\](.+?)\[\/SCHOOL\]\[STATUS\](.+?)\[\/STATUS\]\)/)
    arr.push([matches[1],matches[2]])
}

console.dir(arr)
```

Comment: So let's say I do encode it using JSON in PHP. How do I decode it in JS?

Comment: You use `JSON.Parse`. Or you use jQuery's `.getJSON()` method, which does this automatically for you. They'll return an object whose structure matches the data that you encoded on the PHP page.

Comment: really easy: `my_parsed_object = JSON.parse( the_json_string )`

Comment: server side: `$my_encoded_object = json_encode( $object_to_be_encoded );`

Comment: if you are able to use JSON, it is by far the best solution